# Managing threads in Grails Services

Tags: multithreading, grails, service

So I have a service set up to import a large amount of data from a file the user uploads. I want to the user to be able to continue working on the site while the file is being processed. I accomplished this by creating a thread.

```
Thread.start {
 //work done here
}
```

Now the problem arises that I do not want to have multiple threads running simultaneously. Here is what I tried:

```
class SomeService {

Thread thread = new Thread()

 def serviceMethod() {
   if (!thread?.isAlive()) {
     thread.start {
        //Do work here
     }
   }
 }

}
```

However, this doesn't work. `thread.isAlive()` always return false. Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would consider using an `Executor` instead.

```
import java.util.concurrent.*
import javax.annotation.*

class SomeService {

ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()

 def serviceMethod() {
   executor.execute {
      //Do work here
   }
 }


 @PreDestroy
 void shutdown() {
   executor.shutdownNow()
 }

}
```

Using a `newSingleThreadExecutor` will ensure that tasks execute one after the other.  If there's a background task already running then the next task will be queued up and will start when the running task has finished (`serviceMethod` itself will still return immediately).

You may wish to consider the [executor plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/executor) if your "do work here" involves GORM database access, as that plugin will set up the appropriate persistence context (e.g. Hibernate session) for your background tasks.

Comment: It does involve GORM. Id really prefer not to install a plugin just for this. Can I get around using it?

Comment: @JamesKleeh using `withTransaction` should do it (at least if you're on hibernate, I can't speak for mongo), but the executor plugin is very light weight, so I wouldn't dismiss it out of hand.

Comment: @JamesKleeh, You could grab the relevant pieces that you need in the source code https://github.com/basejump/grails-executor/tree/master/src/groovy/grails/plugin/executor. I would just use the plugin if I were you, in order to avoid dealing with potential persistence issues...

Comment: Thanks - I actually already had it when I was using the thread (duh).

Comment: The plugin documentation says it only works with JDK6. I used the code you have there in JDK7 without issue. Is the plugin documentation old or is it correct?

Comment: @JamesKleeh having looked at the plugin's code in detail in the past I can't see any reason why it shouldn't work on 7, I take "only works on 1.6" to mean "and not on 1.5 or earlier".

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this is to use Spring's `@Async` annotation.

Add the following to `resources.groovy`:

```
beans = {
    xmlns task:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    task.'annotation-driven'('proxy-target-class':true, 'mode':'proxy')
}
```

Any service method you now annotate with `@Async` will run asynchronously, e.g.

```
@Async
def reallyLongRunningProcess() {
    //do some stuff that takes ages
}
```

If you only want one thread to run the import at a time, you could do something like this -

```
class MyService {
    boolean longProcessRunning = false

    @Async
    def reallyLongRunningProcess() {
        if (longProcessRunning) return

        try {
            longProcessRunning = true
            //do some stuff that takes ages
        } finally {
            longProcessRunning = false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, however I could have set up a variable with a flag in the way I was doing it. I just prefer not to do it that way.