# How to start a Java Thread once Grails App is up?

Tags: tomcat, grails

I have a requirement to start a Java Thread after Grails App (Tomcat) is up, What is the correct way to do it ?

Comment: When you say *up*, do you mean when the grails application has completely finished deploying?

Comment: What a weird requirement to "start a thread". It feels like the thread should actually do something, rather than just being started. Why don't you share what you want to do once your grails app is available? There might be a better way than running it in a thread - but you'll only know when you share your intent.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16845026/managing-threads-in-grails-services

Comment: actually Grails is already starting a thread once started, so I guess your requirement is fulfilled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure with the question you have asked but it appears that you need to start some threads once the grails app is up. `Java threads` term doesn't make much sense so let's just call these threads.

You could do this in bootstrap file's init method as init is the place that gets executed just after the application loads.

```
class Bootstrap{
    def init = { servletContext ->

    }

def destroy = {

    }
}
```

you could also kill heavy / costly resources in destroy method .

Hope it helps!